# Create multidimensional numpy array from lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have three lists,

```
list1=['10','20','30']

list2=['40','50','60']

list3=['70','80','90']
```

I want to create a numpy array from these lists. I am using the foloowing code:

```
import numpy as np
list1=['10','20','30']
list2=['40','50','60']
list3=['70','80','90']

data = np.array([[list1],[list2],[list3]])
print data
```

I am getting output as:

```
 [[['10' '20' '30']]
  [['40' '50' '60']]
  [['70' '80' '90']]]
```

But I am expecting output as:

```
[[10 20 30]
 [40 50 50]
 [70 80 90]]
```

Can anybody plz help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `dtype`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list1=['10','20','30']
>>> list2=['40','50','60']
>>> list3=['70','80','90']
>>> np.array([list1, list2, list3], dtype=int)
array([[10, 20, 30],
       [40, 50, 60],
       [70, 80, 90]])
```

According to [`numpy.array` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

> `dtype` : data-type, optional
>
> The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will
> be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the
> sequence. ...

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to mention that specifying dtype results in datatype conversion from strings to ints under the hood.

Comment: @alko, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer with quotation from the documentation.