# Creating multidimensional numpy array from dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe which contains a column were each row contains a list of numbers.

```
| Column A - id | Column B          |
| ------------- | ----------------- |
| 1             | [ 5,2,3,5,6,2,6]  |
| 2             | [ 6,6,3,5,6,2,6]  |
| 3             | [ 5,2,3,1,9,0,4]  |
```

My goal is to retrieve a 2-dimensional numpy array looking like this:

```
array = [[ 5,2,3,5,6,2,6],
         [ 6,6,3,5,6,2,6],
         [ 5,2,3,1,9,0,4]]
```

So far I extracted all values like this

```
customer_examples_data.loc[:,['Column B']].values
```

It creates an numpy array which contains all the values, but not "numpylike" as integer, but as lists of integers:

```
[list([ 5,2,3,5,6,2,6]),
 list([ 6,6,3,5,6,2,6]),
 list([ 5,2,3,1,9,0,4])])
```

at least that's how it looks, when I print it.

I found this post on [Create multidimensional numpy array from lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700002/create-multidimensional-numpy-array-from-lists) and tried the recommended result, but it didn't work in my case.

```
np.array(customer_examples_data['Column B'], dtype = int)
```

How can I convert the data to the above shown numpy data structure?

Comment: `arr = np.vstack(df['Column B'])`